# Ошибка компиляции ядра Kali Nethunter

Tags: linux, c, kernel, kali-linux

Пытаюсь скомпилировать ядро Kali Nethunter под Xiaomi Redmi 4x.
Сейчас у меня стоит Lineage OS 16 (Android 9), взял исходники его ядра.
Настроил по инструкции из wiki репозитория нетхантера:
https://github.com/offensive-security/kali-nethunter/wiki
пункты 7.1 и 7.2.

При попытке компиляции получил кучу мелких ошибок (неправильный путь в #include, в одном месте ошибка типов данных), их исправил.
С одной из ошибок разобраться не могу:
трассировка:

```
drivers/built-in.o: In function `static_key_count':
/home/aleksey/telephone/Nethunter/2/kernel/include/linux/jump_label.h:88: undefined reference to `__tracepoint_tracer_pkt_event'
/home/aleksey/telephone/Nethunter/2/kernel/include/linux/jump_label.h:88:(.text+0x16913c): relocation truncated to fit: R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 against undefined symbol `__tracepoint_tracer_pkt_event'
/home/aleksey/telephone/Nethunter/2/kernel/include/linux/jump_label.h:88: undefined reference to `__tracepoint_tracer_pkt_event'
/home/aleksey/telephone/Nethunter/2/kernel/include/linux/jump_label.h:88: undefined reference to `__tracepoint_rndis_status_rcvd'
/home/aleksey/telephone/Nethunter/2/kernel/include/linux/jump_label.h:88:(.text+0x31a004): relocation truncated to fit: R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 against undefined symbol `__tracepoint_rndis_status_rcvd'
/home/aleksey/telephone/Nethunter/2/kernel/include/linux/jump_label.h:88: undefined reference to `__tracepoint_rndis_status_rcvd'
/home/aleksey/telephone/Nethunter/2/kernel/include/linux/jump_label.h:88: undefined reference to `__tracepoint_rndis_netif_ni'
/home/aleksey/telephone/Nethunter/2/kernel/include/linux/jump_label.h:88:(.text+0x31a3bc): relocation truncated to fit: R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 against undefined symbol `__tracepoint_rndis_netif_ni'
/home/aleksey/telephone/Nethunter/2/kernel/include/linux/jump_label.h:88: undefined reference to `__tracepoint_rndis_netif_ni'
/home/aleksey/telephone/Nethunter/2/kernel/include/linux/jump_label.h:88: undefined reference to `__tracepoint_rndis_tx_dp'
/home/aleksey/telephone/Nethunter/2/kernel/include/linux/jump_label.h:88:(.text+0x31aa88): relocation truncated to fit: R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 against undefined symbol `__tracepoint_rndis_tx_dp'
/home/aleksey/telephone/Nethunter/2/kernel/include/linux/jump_label.h:88: undefined reference to `__tracepoint_rndis_tx_dp'
drivers/built-in.o: In function `btusb_probe':
/home/aleksey/telephone/Nethunter/2/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c:2007: undefined reference to `get_rome_version'
/home/aleksey/telephone/Nethunter/2/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c:2007:(.text+0x7b4bf0): relocation truncated to fit: R_AARCH64_CALL26 against undefined symbol `get_rome_version'
/home/aleksey/telephone/Nethunter/2/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c:2016: undefined reference to `rome_download'
/home/aleksey/telephone/Nethunter/2/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c:2016:(.text+0x7b4c3c): relocation truncated to fit: R_AARCH64_CALL26 against undefined symbol `rome_download'
drivers/built-in.o: In function `btusb_pm_notify':
/home/aleksey/telephone/Nethunter/2/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c:2323: undefined reference to `btusb_pm_sem'
/home/aleksey/telephone/Nethunter/2/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c:2323:(.text+0x7b51a4): relocation truncated to fit: R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 against undefined symbol `btusb_pm_sem'
/home/aleksey/telephone/Nethunter/2/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c:2323: undefined reference to `btusb_pm_sem'
/home/aleksey/telephone/Nethunter/2/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c:2320: undefined reference to `btusb_pm_sem'
/home/aleksey/telephone/Nethunter/2/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c:2320:(.text+0x7b51dc): relocation truncated to fit: R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 against undefined symbol `btusb_pm_sem'
/home/aleksey/telephone/Nethunter/2/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c:2320: undefined reference to `btusb_pm_sem'
drivers/built-in.o: In function `qpnp_flash_led_brightness_set':
/home/aleksey/telephone/Nethunter/2/kernel/drivers/leds/leds-qpnp-flash.c:1925: undefined reference to `wt_flash_flashlight'
/home/aleksey/telephone/Nethunter/2/kernel/drivers/leds/leds-qpnp-flash.c:1925:(.text+0x8199a4): relocation truncated to fit: R_AARCH64_CALL26 against undefined symbol `wt_flash_flashlight'
/home/aleksey/telephone/Nethunter/2/kernel/drivers/leds/leds-qpnp-flash.c:1928: undefined reference to `wt_flash_flashlight'
/home/aleksey/telephone/Nethunter/2/kernel/drivers/leds/leds-qpnp-flash.c:1928:(.text+0x8199b8): relocation truncated to fit: R_AARCH64_CALL26 against undefined symbol `wt_flash_flashlight'
drivers/built-in.o: In function `static_key_count':
/home/aleksey/telephone/Nethunter/2/kernel/include/linux/jump_label.h:88: undefined reference to `__tracepoint_intr_to_poll'
/home/aleksey/telephone/Nethunter/2/kernel/include/linux/jump_label.h:88:(.text+0x8cdc60): additional relocation overflows omitted from the output
/home/aleksey/telephone/Nethunter/2/kernel/include/linux/jump_label.h:88: undefined reference to `__tracepoint_intr_to_poll'
/home/aleksey/telephone/Nethunter/2/kernel/include/linux/jump_label.h:88: undefined reference to `__tracepoint_idle_sleep_enter'
/home/aleksey/telephone/Nethunter/2/kernel/include/linux/jump_label.h:88: undefined reference to `__tracepoint_idle_sleep_exit'
/home/aleksey/telephone/Nethunter/2/kernel/include/linux/jump_label.h:88: undefined reference to `__tracepoint_idle_sleep_enter'
/home/aleksey/telephone/Nethunter/2/kernel/include/linux/jump_label.h:88: undefined reference to `__tracepoint_idle_sleep_exit'
/home/aleksey/telephone/Nethunter/2/kernel/include/linux/jump_label.h:88: undefined reference to `__tracepoint_poll_to_intr'
/home/aleksey/telephone/Nethunter/2/kernel/include/linux/jump_label.h:88: undefined reference to `__tracepoint_poll_to_intr'
/home/aleksey/telephone/Nethunter/2/kernel/include/linux/jump_label.h:88: undefined reference to `__tracepoint_rmnet_ipa_netifni'
/home/aleksey/telephone/Nethunter/2/kernel/include/linux/jump_label.h:88: undefined reference to `__tracepoint_rmnet_ipa_netifni'
/home/aleksey/telephone/Nethunter/2/kernel/include/linux/jump_label.h:88: undefined reference to `__tracepoint_rmnet_ipa_netifrx'
/home/aleksey/telephone/Nethunter/2/kernel/include/linux/jump_label.h:88: undefined reference to `__tracepoint_rmnet_ipa_netifrx'
drivers/built-in.o: In function `btusb_driver_exit':
/home/aleksey/telephone/Nethunter/2/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c:2367: undefined reference to `btusb_pm_sem'
/home/aleksey/telephone/Nethunter/2/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c:2367: undefined reference to `btusb_pm_sem'
Makefile:940: recipe for target 'vmlinux' failed
make: *** [vmlinux] Error 1
```

Соответственно файл jump_label.h (строки 86-89):

```
static inline int static_key_count(struct static_key *key)
{
    return atomic_read(&key->enabled);
}
```

и btusb.c:
строки 2003-2021:

```
if (id->driver_info & BTUSB_ATH3012) {
        struct usb_device *udev = interface_to_usbdev(intf);
        /* Old firmware would otherwise let ath3k driver load
         * patch and sysconfig files */
        err = get_rome_version(udev, &version);
        if (err < 0) {
            if (le16_to_cpu(udev->descriptor.bcdDevice) <= 0x0001)
                BT_INFO("FW for ar3k is yet to be downloaded");
            else
                BT_ERR("Failed to get ROME USB version");
            return -ENODEV;
        }
        BT_INFO("Rome Version: 0x%x", version.rom_version);
        err = rome_download(udev, &version);
        if (err < 0) {
            BT_ERR("Failed to download ROME firmware");
            return -ENODEV;
        }
    }
```

2312-2329:

```
static unsigned long btusb_pm_flags;
#define BTUSB_PM_SUSPEND    (1)
static int btusb_pm_notify(struct notifier_block *b,
                unsigned long event, void *p)
{
    switch (event) {
    case PM_SUSPEND_PREPARE:
        set_bit(BTUSB_PM_SUSPEND, &btusb_pm_flags);
        down_write(&btusb_pm_sem);
        break;
    case PM_POST_SUSPEND:
        up_write(&btusb_pm_sem);
        clear_bit(BTUSB_PM_SUSPEND, &btusb_pm_flags);
        break;
    }

    return NOTIFY_DONE;
}
```

2359-2372:

```
static void __exit btusb_driver_exit(void)
{
    unregister_pm_notifier(&btusb_pm_notifier);
    /*
     * If unregister gets called before resume notification, we need to
     * release the semaphore to avoid deadlock.
     */
    if (test_bit(BTUSB_PM_SUSPEND, &btusb_pm_flags)) {
        up_write(&btusb_pm_sem);
        clear_bit(BTUSB_PM_SUSPEND, &btusb_pm_flags);
    }
    usb_deregister(&btusb_driver);
}
module_exit(btusb_driver_exit);
```

Никак не могу понять, в чем вообще проблема?
Буду рад любым предположениям, что это может быть, и предложениям "прогугли это, это и это".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка

> undefined reference to `__tracepoint_rmnet_ipa_netifrx'

Появляется на этапе **линковки** а вовсе не на этапе **компиляции**. И в её тексте может стоять всё, что угодно на месте *__tracepoint_rmnet_ipa_netifrx*

Эта ошибка говорит о том, что для формирования объектного модуля (в том числе - объектного модуля ядра) линкер не может найти указанные функции (внешние ссылки). Ищите, в какой библиотеке лежат реализации этих функций и подключайте их к сборке объектного модуля.